# reading string from a file in c

Tags: c, string, file

I've got an input file like this:

```
1 2 2 Medium 
1 2 0 Medium
2 1 0 Medium
2 0 2 Medium
```

I am using fscanf() to read in the integer values and that is working fine. does anyone have any ideas how to read in the string and place it in a string variable???

```
int x,y,z; 
char* cs; 
fscanf(fp3,"%d",&x); 
fscanf(fp3,"%d",&y); 
fscanf(fp3,"%d",&z); 
fscanf(fp3,"%s",&cs);
```

Comment: I'd be somewhat worried if you weren't reading it *into* a "string variable" in the first place.

Comment: same just with %s ? and use a char*.

Comment: Why don't you post the code snippet for the fscanf function call you're using ?

Comment: int x,y,z;
   char* cs;
   fscanf(fp3,"%d",&x);
   fscanf(fp3,"%d",&y);
   fscanf(fp3,"%d",&z);
   fscanf(fp3,"%s",&cs);

Comment: scanning the string doesnt work. im getting run time errors

Comment: ok first error was cs is being used without being initialized. then i set cs to the empty string and got the error: Unhandled exception at 0x58766551

Answer (score 2):

You need already allocated space to store the string. Try something like this:

```
int x,y,z; 
char cs[20];
fscanf(fp3,"%d",&x); 
fscanf(fp3,"%d",&y); 
fscanf(fp3,"%d",&z); 
fscanf(fp3,"%19s",cs);
```

You can also scan for all the values at once:

```
fscanf(fp3,"%d %d %d %19s", &x, &y, &z, cs);
```

N.B: Always use `%<length>s` in a scanf pattern to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: I dont think 'cs' should be with &, it is an array.

Comment: using [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Although you'll have to do some pointer voodoo on the char array. like, use `&cs[0]` instead of `cs`. normal strings which are char* are fine. So: `strcmp(str1, &cs[0]);`

Comment: Note that you should test the return value from fscanf. It it is not 4 then some of the conversions failed or the end of file was reached.

Comment: You can read the input in a single instruction (I like it better): `if (fscanf(fp3, "%d%d%d%s", &x, &y, &z, cs) != 4) /* error */;`

Answer (score 1):

2 things to say:

1. It looks nicer when you use **one** format string
2. You should use a loop

Here's some code:

```
int a,b,c;
char str[256];
while(fscanf(fd, "%d %d %d %s ", &a, &b, &c, str) == 4){
    //get some coffee
}
```

this is a standard while not End of File loop. Also, `str` doesn't need `&` because it already is a pointer and doesn't need to be referenced like `a`, `b` or `c`. The space at the end of the format string, after `%s`, means it will stop once that one space is read. This way it is not included in the string `str`.

Comment: This is undefined behavior; `str` is uninitialized and points nowhere. That's why the OP gets the unhandled exception.

Comment: Better test against the number of conversions rather than `EOF`

Comment: fixed my answer, ran it too.

Comment: you may substitute `&str[0]` by `str`

Comment: yea, just ran with `str` and it works. I wasn't sure if C cared about array pointers vs normal pointers.

Comment: The space at the end of the format string is an error! First: `"%s"` already stops at whitespace, leaving the whitespace in the input buffer ready for the next read operation. The extra space in the format string makes `fscanf` ignore the whitespace -- **as many as it can** -- resulting in an apparent crash of the program while it "eats" ENTERs. The `fscanf()` will only stop when it gets to something that is not whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for two things:

- You need to reserve a buffer to copy the string into.
- Also never ever use a plain "%s" scanf pattern. It should be forbidden. Instead insert the length of the buffer, minus 1 between the `%` and the `s`. E.g., "%7s" for an 8 byte buffer.